# Can I allow users to install BlackBerry 10 theme from my app?

Tags: themes, blackberry-10

I'm trying to create a Blackberry 10 app to enable users to install theme directly within it instead of from Blackberry App World. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: you should contact direct with the blackberry manufacturers

Comment: I have contacted them. The answer is that Blackberry 10 won't support theming anymore. Their post is here http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/10/blackberry-10-theme-development/